# unable to display real time data,it requires to open the app again and again to load new data from Fiebase data base

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

i am loading the user input data onto this screen ,but only the data entered before opening the app is displayed,new data entries made by user are not displayed until we re-open the app.

this is my code,using this data from database is displayed but not the latest updates made by the user.

```
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state ={
        persons:[]
    }
}

renderItem =({item}) => {
    const start = 'mailto:';
    let mail= item.email;
    const end = '?subject=Application for Job';
    const add = start.concat(mail,end);
    console.log(item.email);
    return(
        <View style={{fles:1, flexDirection:'column',marginBottom:5,marginLeft:5,marginRight:5, borderRadius: 4, borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: '#6d7ba5',}}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Job Title:  {item.JobTitle}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text2}>Job Description:  {item.JobDesc}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text2}>Working Hours:  {item.Timing}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text2}selectable={true}
            onPress={() => Linking.openURL(add)}>Payment:  {item.Payment}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text2} selectable={true}
            onPress={() => Linking.openURL(add)}>Contact Info:  {item.Number}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text2} selectable={true}
            onPress={() => Linking.openURL(add)} >Email:  {item.Email}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text2} selectable={true}
            onPress={() => Linking.openURL(add)}>Remark:  {item.Remark}</Text>
        </View>
    )

}
componentDidMount(){
    const url ='https://parttimer-88182.firebaseio.com/users.json';

    axios.get(url).then(res =>{
        const persons = res.data;
        console.log(Object.entries(persons));
        this.setState({persons});
    }); 


}


refreshHandler(){
    const url ='https://parttimer-88182.firebaseio.com/users.json';

    axios.get(url).then(res =>{
        const persons = res.data;
        console.log(Object.entries(persons));
        this.setState({persons});
    }); 


}
render() {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ImageBackground source ={require('../../assets/Background/back2.jpg')} style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}}>
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <Header style={{height:65,backgroundColor:'transparent'}}>                          
                    <Icon name='angle-double-right' style={styles.icon} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('openDrawer')} />
                    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color:'black' ,fontSize:30,marginTop:20 }} >Explore Adds</Text>
                    <Icon name='info-circle' style={styles.icon2} onPress={this._simpleAlertHandler} />
                </Header>

                <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, fontWeight: '700',marginTop:5, paddingHorizontal: 20 ,backgroundColor:'rgba(217,224,244,0.7)'}}>
                            Select your desired job here !
                </Text>

                <View style={{ height:130,backgroundColor:'rgba(217,224,244.0.7)',borderRadius: 4, borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: '#6d7ba5'}}>
                    <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                        <Category 
                            imageUri={require('../../assets/experiences.jpg')}
                            name="Janta Travels"/>
                        <Category 
                            imageUri={require('../../assets/rajat.jpg')}
                            name="HistoryGuider" />
                        <Category 
                            imageUri={require('../../assets/army.jpg')}
                            name="Army Trainers"/>
                        <Category 
                            imageUri={require('../../assets/experiences.jpg')}
                            name="Job 1"/>

                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1,marginTop:5}}> 
                    <FlatList
                        data={Object.entries(this.state.persons).map(item =>(item[1]))}
                        renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    />
                    <View style={{height:30}} >
                    <Button title="    REFRESH    " onPress={this.refreshHandler}
                    color='#841585' borderRadius={50} />

                    </View>
                </View>

            </View>
            </ImageBackground>
    </SafeAreaView>        
    );
}
```

}

Can anyone tell me how to load the most recent input made by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the REST API of the Firebase Realtime Database, which means that the data is only gotten once, when you call `axios.get(url)`.

If you want to get realtime updates from Firebase, consider using the Firebase SDK to do so. For example the [React Native Firebase SDK](https://rnfirebase.io/) for the Firebase Realtime Database is quite mature, and uses Firebase's native wire protocol to listen for realtime updates. To get started with the API for this, have a look at [rnfirebase.io](https://rnfirebase.io/)and at the [Firebase documentation for web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start).

If you're really insistent on *not* using an SDK, you can have a look at Firebase's [REST streaming protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming), which exposes realtime updates over the REST API. Just note that you'll likely find yourself recreating significant parts of the Firebase SDK in your own code that way.